# WSO2 ESB - How to select methods to expose in proxy services

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Source `wsdl` contains 10 methods, but we want to expose only 2 of the methods in the proxy service.

Is it possible?
If possible then how should we achieve it?

Comment: Expose all 10 just throw a not implemented exception on the ones you have not implemented then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the wsdl to have only those two operations  and attach that to proxy conf (ie: using `<publishWSDL>` option)

Comment: that's the first thing i thought but it can be exhausting and cumbersome in some cases.